# how to preserve the order of tags while coverting xml to json in python using xmlutils

Tags: python, xml, json

I have following xml code chunk:

    
       offset
    
    
      len
    
    
       p_val

while i covert it to json using below python code the order of tags are changing as below:

converter = xml2json("test.xml", "test.json", encoding="utf-8")
converter.convert()

output is:

"APIAttr": {
    "p_val": {

```
        "name": "p_val", 

       }, 
 "len": {
        "name": "len", 

         },
```

"offset": {
            "name": "offset",

```
         }
   }
```

i want :
 "APIAttr": {
    "offset": {

```
        "name": "p_val", 

       }, 
 "len": {
        "name": "len", 

         },
```

"p_val": {
            "name": "offset",

```
         }
   }
```

how do i preserve the order of tags from xml to json please let me know if there is any way in python

Comment: Better to be asked at http://stackoverflow.com ...

Comment: Until Python 3.6 dictionaries are unordered. I think the JSON spec defines them like that as well. Use a list if you want ordered data.